# Windows phone update local database when received toast notification in background

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, push-notification, mpns, local-database

I am using toast push notifications in my Windows Phone 8 app. When I receive these notifications, I would like to update the local database of my app regardless whether the app is in foreground, background or not running.

Do you know if is that possible? If not, is there another way in order to do this?

Thank you in advance